# Unable to pip install tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

After facing several errors with tensorflow not detecting GPU and python programs not functioning properly. I decided to re-install python and so I decided to install **python 3.6.8** and it's successfully installed. 
Now am trying to **pip install** packages and I see **I cannot install tensorflow package**. It's showing me this below error,

[image]

Apart from the tensorflow package, I was able to install other packages like numpy, pandas, opencv without any issues. 
***I request you to please look into this issue and help me resolve this problem.***

Answer (score 0):

**Tensorflow can only be downloaded on python 64 bit versions**. That is the reason it wasn't able to install tensorflow, since it was 32bit version. Now after reinstalling **python 3.6.8 64 bit** version, it fixed the issue.